# Prompt_Tookit with similar functions to CMD2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am developing a program that is going to use Prompt_Toolkit. I am revising my current code which is using CMD2. The issue I run into CMD2 is printing to the screen by multiple threads. If I am in the middle of typing into the console and a thread prints, it will clobber my input.

Prompt_toolkit fixes this by providing two different screens. It has the output screen and the input line.

CMD2 has a lot of nice features such as the ability to create functions very simply by doing:

```
do_myfunction():
    print("This is my function.")

help_myfunction():
    print("Help menu for myfunction.")
```

This is extremely important to my project because I need to accept input from the user which would then run commands. An example of what the user would input is something like

```
prompt> socket -listen 127.0.0.1 -port 4444
prompt> run -task restart
etc.
```

PT does not provide a simple way of doing this. I have read that it is not possible to include CMD2 into PT without rebuilding the majority of it, which I don't think I have the time or knowledge to dig that deep.

I am looking for any alternatives or directions to go that would send me in the right direction.

Thanks.